# Questions about 33:56

Tags: quran, quran-translation, arabic-translation, translation

In Qur'an 33:56, the translation is
"Indeed, Allah showers His blessings upon the Prophet, and His angels pray for him. O  believers! Invoke Allah’s blessings upon him, and salute him with worthy greetings of peace."

But somebody said the correct one is
"Indeed, God and his angels pray for the Prophet"

The Arabic word for pray is "[يصلى](https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/pray/)" and the arabic word for "send blessings on" is "[صلى على](https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/send-blessings/)" and the word in the qur'an is "يُصَلُّوْنَ"

So Pray = "Yusalli"

Send blessings on = "Salli 'ala"

Word in the qur'an = "Yusalluna"

I know this is incorrect bcs ppl who can speak Arabic would notice about this ofc. However, i can't speak Arabic (i can only read it), so how do i refute this? Thanks.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: The verb in Arabic is always referred to in the masculine past form of the 3rd person singular "he" so (he) prayed is صلى (sallaa) the present form is (he) prays يصلي (yusalli or yusallee) and if we refer to them (the sahabah as in the related verse) we say (they) pray يصلون. However as-Salaat الصلاة (the prayer) in Arabic literally means performing du'a.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever said this shows a lack of even basic Arabic.

The words يصلى and صلى are the same verbs except that the first is in present tense and the second is in past tense. Anyone who knows even a bit of Arabic can tell you that.

The difference comes from the على after it. The phrase صلى على (and its present form obviously as well: يصلى على) is used to mean "send blessings on."

And the verse says يُصَلُّونَ عَلَى النَّبِيِّ.

Comment: Thank you brother for answering.